# Changing an IP Address in Powershell

Tags: powershell, compare, range, ip-address

I am trying to get an IP address from the computer and then check the address to see if it is in a certain range. However I'm really unsure of how exactly to do this. I have figured out how to get the IP address form the computer but then checking it against the range is another story...

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |   Where-Object { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } |   Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress } |   Foreach-Object { [IPAddress]$_ } |   Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork'  } |   Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddressToString }

If ($_.IPAddressToString -eq 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.0.50)
{Write-host $_.IPAddressToString}
else ($_.IPAddressToString -ne 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.0.50)
{$_.IPAddressToString = 192.168.0.15}
```

The first line is what I am using to get the IP address. I was looping up if statements so that if the address was in the range then it won't do anything but output the address. I made an else statement for the IP address to be changed if the IP is not in the right range.

There isn't anything that I found that is in between. I don't know how to script out 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.0.50. I also couldn't really find anything that allows me to check that the IP address is in that range, so I just used equal to and not equal. Needless to say it obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change to fit your low and high.

```
$ipLow = [IPAddress] "192.168.9.10"
$ipHigh = [IPAddress] "192.168.9.60"

[Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | ? {$_.OperationalStatus -eq "Up"} | % {
    $addrs = $_.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
    if ($addrs) {
        foreach ($addr in $addrs) {
            if ($addr.Address.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork') {
                if ($addr.Address.Address -ge $ipLow.Address -and $addr.Address.Address -le $ipHigh.Address) {
                    $addr.Address
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```